# Java Script: Passing variables between html pages

Tags: javascript, html

I am practicing making an e-commerce site. I am struggling passing my javascript variable between the shopping cart page to the checkout page. I tried following this example:

```html
page one:
<a href="example2.html?myVar1=42&myVar2=66" >LINK</a>

page 2:

var qs = new Querystring();

var v1 = qs.get("myVar1");

var v2 = qs.get("myVar2");
```

I could not get it to work because my webpage threw an error about not recognizing QueryString, so I am currently trying like this by using window.localStorage as follows:

```html
Page 01:

<button class="checkout" type="button" onClick="window.location.href='checkout.html'; window.localStorage.setItem("total",total)">Checkout</button>


Page 2:

var name = window.localStorage.getItem("total");
```

Currently, I am throwing a console.log(total) on the 2nd page but it returns "null" each time. Any idea why it's not catching the value from the first page? Please help.
If you have suggestions or a solution for either method, it would be much appreciated. I feel like I'm really close with the 2nd method, I may just be missing something on the page 1 portion, thanks in advance.

Comment: While using `localStorage` is not an unreasonable solution, you're not really doing the javascript stuff inline in the html are you?  Also, if you're going to use localStorage, you'd better check if it's available for the user and fail gracefully if not. This page has a good example showing how to check if it's available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: what does 'could not get it to work' mean? Your snippets are not really valid

Comment: `queryString()` is not a built-in javascript function. You probably want to look in `window.location.search` for the query string.

Comment: there's `URL.searchParams.get`

Answer (score 1):

To fix your first method (passing variables between pages via a query string), you'd probably want something like:

```
// page one:
<a href="example2.html?myVar1=42&myVar2=66" >LINK</a>

// page 2:

var query = window.location.search;
if( typeof query !== 'undefined' ) {
    var params = {},
        parts
    ;
    // take off the ? and split into groups of key=value strings
    query = query.replace('?','').split('&');

    // split key=value strings into a usable object
    for(var i=0;i<query.length;i++){
        parts = query[i].split('=');
        params[ parts[0] ] = parts[1];
    }

    // now access your variables like so:

    params.myVar1 // is now "42" (a string)
    params.myVar2 // "66"

}
```

Comment: On a modern browser, you can just use the `URL` object, alternatively, a library (which is what I think the poster is attempting but it's somehow not working out for them). Hacking your own querystring parser is unnecessary and likely a bad idea because there are zillions of things that can go wrong. Take a look at http://unixpapa.com/js/querystring.html

Comment: `URLSearchParams` doesn't seem to be available in a bunch of desktop and mobile browsers.